# animateMotion Controlling with script

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

i've made a Path with SVG, and i'm making a ball to move along it.

But is there anyway i can control de movement of the ball?

Like, the ball starts stoped, while i press the Right Arrow on the keyboard, the ball moves Clockwise, and when i press the left arrow, the ball moves Counter-Clockwise...

is it possible?

here is the svg code:

```
<svg width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<!-- Draw the outline of the motion path in grey, along
     with 2 small circles at key points -->
<path d="M66,89.32c18,143,154,82,97,118s-187,38-152,102s114,105,163,74
s89-111,89-127s18-128,13-155s-29-67-57-80s-47-14-62-17s-17-8-32,0s-40,23-47,30s-11,20-16,24s-14,29-14,29L66,89.32z" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>

<!-- Here is a red circle which will be moved along the motion path. -->
<circle cx="" cy="" r="5" fill="red">

    <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
    <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
       <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
</circle>
```

I put my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/fPQv2/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing i can do, is that i've add this script, so i can pause and unpause the animation... but still not what im looking for....

```
var pause = document.getElementById('draw');
var unPause = document.getElementById('draw');

function parar(){
    pause.pauseAnimations();
}
function voltar(){
    unPause.unpauseAnimations();
}

    $(window).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            setTimeout(voltar,10);
            setTimeout(parar,500);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use accessKey but that only works with keys that translate to a character. For instance changing to this...

```
    <animateMotion begin="accessKey(1)" end="accessKey(2)" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
       <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
```

Means that you can start the animation by pressing 1 and stop it by pressing 2. If you wanted to run the animation backwards you'd need another path which runs back to front and another animateMotion which refers to that backwards path. That animateMotion could start and stop with accessKeys reversed. I've only tested this on Firefox but I believe this is implemented on Opera and probably elsewhere too.

Note that without scripting you can't pause an animation so when you press the access keys you'll see the animation restart from the beginning again. If you want pausing you'll need to call [pauseAnimations()](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__pauseAnimations) on the parent `<svg>` element when a key is pressed.

If you want something more interactive then SMIL is not the best solution, just position the ball at some x/y location using javascript. You can use [getPointAtLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength) to figure out where on the path it should go.

Comment: Thanks for that man!

But what i really need to do is like... step by step... like.. i press the (1), the ball moves like "1frame" and pauses....

And so go on....

Answer (score 0):

if you want the animate as soon as element append page, set 'begin' to 'indefinite' and begin the animate call its .beginElement();

```
var animateMotion = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'animateMotion');
animateMotion.setAttribute('begin', 'indefinite');
//append animateMotion to the page
animateMotion.beginElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pauseAnimations()` and control it using `setCurrentTime(time)`. Those are methods for the svg element.